# Get asset folder and filename together

Tags: assets

I am using a 3rd party service to run the image processing so I do not need full URL's for the images. I just need it to spit out the relative path name of the asset, not the absolute URL. I seem to be able to get either the `asset.folder` or the `asset.filename` but not both.

```
{% if entry.homepageImage|length %}
{% set asset = entry.homepageImage.first() %}
  <img ix-path="{{ asset.filename }}" alt="Test Image">
{% endif %}
```

I did try including the folder when setting the asset but that didn't work either, plus seems quite convoluted for something relatively simple.

```
{% set asset = entry.homepageImage.folderId(2).first() %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AssetFileModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/AssetFileModel)'s [getPath](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/AssetFileModel#getPath-detail) should do what you're looking for.

```
<img ix-path="{{ asset.getPath() }}" alt="Test Image">
```

Comment: For some reason that isn't including the folder in the path, just the filename

Comment: If it's just the filename, then that means the file is in the root of your Asset source path.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct, there is something wrong with the asset folder I think.